# SEGFAULT when accessing a singleton child class with shared pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, segmentation-fault, singleton, shared-ptr

I have a template class `ISingleton`

```
class ISingleton
{
public:
    static T* getInstance()
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(mMutex);
        if (mInstance == NULL)
        {
            mInstance = new T();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    static void destroy()
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> guard(mMutex);
        delete mInstance;
        mInstance = NULL;
    }

    ISingleton(ISingleton const&) = delete;
    ISingleton& operator =(ISingleton const&) = delete;

protected:
    ISingleton()
    {
    }

    virtual ~ISingleton()
    {
    }

private:

    static T* mInstance;
    static mutex mMutex;
};
```

a parent class and a child class of `Parent` which is a singleton

```
class Parent
{
    public:
        Parent(string name) { mName = name; }
        virtual ~Parent();
        string getName(){ return mName; }
    private:
        string mName;
}

class Child : public Parent, public ISingleton<Child>
{
    public:
        virtual ~Child();
    private:
        Child() { mName = "child"; }
        friend ISingleton<Child>;
};
```

and I create a shared pointer to a singleton like this

```
void foo()
{
    shared_ptr<Parent> module(Child::getInstance());
}
Parent *c = Child::getInstance();
c->getName(); //SEGFAULT
```

The problem occurs if the `shared_ptr'`s reference count reaches zero. The next call to `Child::getName` will cause a segfault. I can't figure out if it's a problem of inheritance or with the implementation of the singleton itself. Thanks for advice!

Comment: You should not stoke singleton address into a smart pointer. You may return a shared_pointer, but then all your synchronization is out of control anyway.

Comment: Aren't static local variables guaranteed to be race-free in initialization since C++11?

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm forced to pass a shared_ptr to an object of type Parent to an API. In my case it's of type Child which is a singleton. I know there are workarounds, but I'm highly interested what's the root cause of the SEGFAULT here.

Comment: @StenSoft Yes, of course. Just an early morning brain fart on my side.

Comment: @tsuki Yes, C++11 allows for a much simpler implementation without mutexes or data members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is not what is considered a singleton in C++. A singleton is never destroyed and recreated so storing it in a smart pointer makes no sense.

But if you want to destroy it with the smart pointer, you need to tell the smart pointer how to do it. By default, the smart pointer calls `operator delete`. You may define class-specific `operator delete` for that in `ISingleton`:

```
void operator delete(void *me) noexcept
{
    // Possibly assert(me == mInstance);
    mInstance = nullptr;
    ::operator delete(me);
}
```

Or you can provide the smart pointer with a lambda that will call `destroy` instead of `delete`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Parent> module(Child::getInstance(),
        [](Parent*){ Child::destroy(); });
```

Comment: Implementing the delete operator solves the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You should not stoke singleton address into a smart pointer, as it is the singleton which owns the resource.

As you require to have a non-*owning* `shared_ptr`, you may use an empty deleter:

```
std::shared_ptr<Parent> dummy_ptr(Child::getInstance(), [](Parent*){/*Nothing*/});
```

but changing the method to not take a `shared_ptr` seems better.